# C# and access trying to order and change order

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a Access Database that i manipulate though a c# program.
i am trying to get a order of items that satisfy certain conditions.and be able to change the order.

my idea is to copy the unique key in to another field then order by that field and have a button that moves up and a button that moves down.is this the right way to go about this ?

Comment: you can do this with a check box for example if checked then pass in the Checked.State and have a parameter in your query that checks if that value passed in is checked or not then in the `Order By` clause you could have `Order By `ASC or DESC` passing in a variable / parameter. also if you are showing the data in a DataGridView of JQGrid then you can add the sorting to the columns if it's a DataGridView and if you are familiar with JQGrid it allows you to sort clicking on the up or down arrows there are tons of ways to do this perhaps you could share some code so we can see what you are doing

Comment: you could go even further if you allow columns to be movable in the DataGridView, then based on the order you could dynamically construct a query to pull back the columns based on their order in the grid after pushing a button.. very doable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a separate column in a table called Order for example makes sense, as does allowing a user to re-order the items and save it back to the database.  Maybe drag/drop or something for re-ordering would be a bit less clunky than buttons, but I guess it depends if your c# application is winforms, wpf, web, etc. as to how easy that is.